# How to make animation changing background image?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am developing Microsoft Store App with UWP and i am using XAML and C#.
I want to randomy change background image with a opacity animation.

My code is in below.

This function  execute with `Task.Run(InitializeWorks);`

```
    private async void InitializeWorks()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
        {
            BackgroundImage.Opacity = 0;
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var backgroundImageFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\BackgroundImages");
                    var backgroundImageFiles = await backgroundImageFolder.GetFilesAsync();
                    BackgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(backgroundImageFiles[new Random().Next(0, backgroundImageFiles.Count)].Path));
                    for (double i = BackgroundImage.Opacity; i <= 0.1; i += 0.001)
                    {
                        BackgroundImage.Opacity = i;
                        await Task.Delay(10);
                    }
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                    for (double i = BackgroundImage.Opacity; i >= 0; i -= 0.001)
                    {
                        BackgroundImage.Opacity = i;
                        await Task.Delay(10);
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //
            }

        });

    }
```

1. What is performance of this code can i use ? Have a inconvenience
   of this async task? Can it occurs any errors ?
2. How to make a changing animation with XAML ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add a opacity animation to BackgroundImage in XAML?

Comment: No, if BackgroundImage is change then i want xaml create a opacity animation from 0.1 to 0 after again 0.1 @faywang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with @faywang @mm8

Animation of XML with Storyboard;

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="BackgroundImageStoryboardIncrease">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundImage"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0"
            To="0.15"
            Duration="0:0:2" />
    </Storyboard>
    <Storyboard x:Name="BackgroundImageStoryboardDecrease">
        <DoubleAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundImage"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
            From="0.15"
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:2" />
    </Storyboard>
```

C# Change Event and Stand 10 sec :

```
    private async void InitializeFrontWorks()
    {
        // Animations
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
        };
        var backgroundImageFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\BackgroundImages");
        var backgroundImageFiles = await backgroundImageFolder.GetFilesAsync();
        AnimationBackgroundImage(backgroundImageFiles);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += delegate
        {
            AnimationBackgroundImage(backgroundImageFiles);
        };
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
    private void AnimationBackgroundImage(IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> backgroundImageFiles)
    {
        BackgroundImageStoryboardDecrease.Begin();
        BackgroundImageStoryboardDecrease.Completed += delegate
        {
            BackgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(backgroundImageFiles[new Random().Next(0, backgroundImageFiles.Count)].Path));
            BackgroundImageStoryboardIncrease.Begin();
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `GetFolderAsync` or `GetFilesAsync` in XAML but I would advice you to replace the `while` loop with a [DispatcherTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer) that changes the background at regular intervals.

The `Tick` event will be raised on the UI thread which means that it's safe to access your UI elements in the event handler. The async methods won't block.

Comment: xaml cannot access any backend functions. However can XAML make any animation if source change ?

Comment: Look into [Storyboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.storyboard).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following animation in XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
<Storyboard x:Name="MyStoryboard">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundImage">​
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>​
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3" Value="0.1"/>​
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="0"/>​
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>​
        </Storyboard>​
</Page.Resources>
```

Code-behind:

You can use **StoryBoard.Begin** to start **Opacity** animation and the animation has a **Completed** event.You can subscribe it to listen whether the animation completes.When the animation completes,you can invoke **InitializeWorks()** method to change BackgroundImage again.This way of writing replaces your **While** method.

```
private async void InitializeWorks()
        {​
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>​
            {​
                BackgroundImage.Opacity = 0;​
                try​
                {​
                   ​
                    var backgroundImageFolder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync(@"Assets\BackgroundImages");​
                    var backgroundImageFiles = await backgroundImageFolder.GetFilesAsync();​
                    BackgroundImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(backgroundImageFiles[new Random().Next(0, backgroundImageFiles.Count)].Path));​
                    MyStoryboard.Begin();​
                    MyStoryboard.Completed += MyStoryboard_Completed;​
                }​
                catch (Exception e)​
                {​
                    //​
                }​
​
            });​
​
        }

private void MyStoryboard_Completed(object sender, object e)
        {​
            InitializeWorks();​
        }
```

Comment: this solution just work for animation. image dont stand.